# Android ListView and Scroll problem

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `LinearLayout` with a number of `TextView` followed by a `ListView` at the bottom - see code below.

The problem is the TextView/CheckBox's take around 75% of the screen - ListView then has a scroll inside it at the bottom, not massively usable - how do I disable the ListView scroll and enable the whole LinearLayout Scroll. Please provide some example code.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CCCCCC">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/_text_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text1"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

           <CheckBox ..../>
           <CheckBox ..../>
           <TextView android:id="@+id/_text_title" ..../>
           <CheckBox ..../>
           <CheckBox ..../>
       <ListView .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your activity a ListActivity?

Comment: It can be either, but at the moment its an Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view. It will not work. if you run into such a problem you have a UI design flaw. An UI redesign/rethink is imminent.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, So I found the solution to this.

I dont have the code to hand, but roughly speaking what I did was,

1. create new class extending ListView
2. Override the onMeasure method,
3. Using the data set I have - I know the hight of each row,  I calculate the height of the list and set this manually.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. To remove this you have to put your list view in sap rate layout.